# When I open CMD from Java, I cannot change the Directory

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem with my Java program where I have a button that opens the command prompt and opens a batch file to run a series of commands. To do this, I need to change directory. 
Here is my code:

```
private void CommandPromptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    try {
        new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").start();
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
            //I need to change the directory in command prompt and I do not want to use escape
            "cmd.exe","/c","start","cd C:\Users\Faz"
        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TMISGUIInstallerPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions and advice are appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure what you meant by "Do not want to use escape" but without escape characters, "C:\Users\Faz" is not a valid Java String.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start cd \"C:\\Users\\Faz\" && dir");
```

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard using  \\\  in place of  \\  won't even compile, so I didn't get your purpose of edit!.

Comment: What are you talking about? You added that, not me. I simply changed your code format.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the directory in the `ProcessBuilder` using the `ProcessBuilder#directory()` and then `start` the process. Here is a sample code:

```
ProcessBuilder start = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start");
        start.directory(new File("C:\\Users"));
        start.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted Aukta's answer, it should solve your problem.

But as you asked:

> To do this, I need to change directory.

Actually with [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and its [`directory(File directory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-), we can easily set the *working directory*. Here is a simple demo to list all files in a specified directory to show you how it can be used.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls"); // pass in your command and options;
    processBuilder.directory(new File("/home")); // specify you directory here;
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
gitlab-runner
hearen
ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help and suggestions. I have finally found an answer. I forgot to add that I tried using Java runtime but that does not run all commands. I have found that if I add another quotation mark, I can change the directory.

```
private void CommandPromptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
try {
    new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").start();
    java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
        //I need to change the directory in command prompt and I do not want to use escape
        "cmd.exe","/c","start","cd C:\"Users\"Faz"
    });

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TMISGUIInstallerPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}

Thank you for all of your help. Probs submit some more questions later. Cheers!